# Missing typings in return type of function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have problem with function `createRouting` which should return actually the same as it gets.
But currently it return the simplest representation of it gets.
Here is code:

```js
type ParamValue = number | string;
type Params<Keys extends string = string> = {
  [K in Keys]: (rawParams: Record<string, ParamValue>) => ParamValue;
};
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

class RouteConfig<RouteKey, P extends Params> {
  constructor(
    public config: {
      params?: P;
      name?: RouteKey;
      validate: (
        loc: string,
        params: NoInfer<P> extends Params<infer PKeys>
          ? { [K in PKeys]: ReturnType<P[K]> }
          : never,
      ) => boolean;
      path: (
        params: NoInfer<P> extends Params<infer PKeys>
          ? { [K in PKeys]: ReturnType<P[K]> }
          : never,
      ) => string;
    },
  ) {}
}

const enum RouteName {
  Main,
}

export const createRouting = <RouteKeys extends string | number, T = any>(
  routes: {
    [K in RouteKeys]: T;
  },
): {
  [K in RouteKeys]: T extends RouteConfig<infer RK, infer RP>
    ? RP extends Params<infer PK>
      ? RouteConfig<RK, Params<PK>>
      : never
    : never;
} => {
  return routes as any;
};

const routing = createRouting<RouteName>({
  [RouteName.Main]: new RouteConfig({
    name: RouteName.Main as const,
    params: {
      foo: (params) => (params.foo && +params.foo) || 0,
      bar: () => 66,
    } as const,
    validate: (location, params) => {
      const barExp = params.bar.toExponential(15);
      const fooExp = params.foo.toExponential(15);

      if (barExp + fooExp) return true;

      return true;
    },
    path: ({ foo }) => `/${foo}`,
  }),
});

routing[RouteName.Main].config.params.foo;
```

On the last code line `params` shouldn't be undefined and have two keys `foo` and `bar`

Comment: Is it that `params?: P` is optional in your RouteConfig constructor?

Comment: Hi @willis ! Yes it is optional

Comment: Isn't that your problem then? `params` is optional, so you need to check for its existence before referencing `params.foo` and `params.bar`.